# How do I get my Sender Policy Framework (SPF) to pass?

Tags: dns, actionmailer, postfix-mta, spam, spf

I'm sending mails from my rails application but for some reason I never get SPF to pass, its always saying either failed or neutral.

I've got forward and reverse DNS set up (what I think is correct).  I followed the guides [here](http://articles.slicehost.com/email) to no avail.  The good thing is that my mail doesn't end up in spam, but thats not enough for me, I want SPF to pass.  If anyone can help me it would be appreciated.

I have my hostname set to `mail.example.com`.  I have my reverse DNS set to the same.  However, when I send mail I want it to come from help@example.com, not from help@mail.example.com.  When I email from help@mail.example.com I get a neutral SPF, but when i change it to help@example.com, it fails.  The way I understand is that if its still coming from the FQDN it should pass, but it doesn't.

These are my DNS records:

```
A = mail xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
A = example. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
A = www xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
MX = example. mailstore1.secureserver.net.
MX = example. smtp.secureserver.net.
MX = example. mail.example.com.
TXT = v=spf1 mx include:mail.example.com -all.
```

The first 2 MX records are from godaddy, but I'm hosting the site with slicehost.  Also, I have a couple of CNAME and NS records that I don't think are helpful but Im mentioning in  case they are.

I'm using postfix on Ubuntu and rails 3.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the header of one of my failed mails

```
Delivered-To: myemail@gmail.com
Received: by 10.229.49.65 with SMTP id u1cs60507qcf;
        Mon, 12 Dec 2011 19:20:11 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.42.150.135 with SMTP id a7mr13973149icw.53.1323746409644;
        Mon, 12 Dec 2011 19:20:09 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <help@example.com>
Received: from mail.example.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id y15si2866827ibk.138.2011.12.12.19.20.09;
        Mon, 12 Dec 2011 19:20:09 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of help@example.com does not designate xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) client-ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=hardfail (google.com: domain of help@example.com does not designate xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mail=help@example.com
Received: from localhost.localdomain (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id B6BB31C1F5D
    for <myemail@gmail.com>; Tue, 13 Dec 2011 03:20:08 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2011 03:20:08 +0000
From: Example <help@example.com>
To: myemail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <4ee6c468a8150_7e4e4ea930773a1@mail.example.com.mail>
Subject: Password Reset
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

**SOLUTION:**
Put quotes around the spf record, mine now looks like this:

```
TXT = "v=spf1 mx include:mail.example.com -all"
```

Comment: What is the domain name to which you attached the SPF record? mail.example.com or example.com?

Comment: its a TXT record set for mydomain.com.

Comment: How do you check, SPF is passing or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary based on the comments:
The quotes are important in the content of a TXT record. Space counts as a separator. I have met a DNS user interface where sloppily entering v=spf1 -all (note that quotes are missing) resulted in two atoms "v=spf1" "-all" instead of a single atom "v=spf1 -all". Only the latter will work.

Your SPF record is messed up. "include" is a redirection. You are saying that the SPF record of example.com is the SPF record of mail.example.com, and based on your question I guess this is not what you want. You should include all relevant DNS information (MX, A, TXT, SPF) in your question. Something like:

```
example.com.  IN TXT "v=spf1 include:example.net -all"
example.net.  IN TXT "v=spf1 mx -all"
```

Comment: I put the include there because without it I was getting a fail no matter what.  I've updated my post to include more DNS info, let me know if its enough or there is something specific your looking for?

Comment: Which servers will be used to *send* mail in the name of your domain? Are you sure you really specify your domain in the envelope as a reverse-path (xyz@example.com)? Moreover, are you sure that your mail server identifies itself with a correct HELO name, specifically mail.example.com? You may want to include the headers of one of your mails received by gmail for example. I am interested in the Return-Path and the Received-SPF headers. (Note that I am reluctant to type your example domain mydomain... because that is a real company.)

Comment: One other thing: the quotes are important in the content of a TXT record. Space counts as a separator. I have met a DNS user interface where sloppily entering v=spf1 -all (note that quotes are missing) resulted in two atoms "v=spf1" "-all" instead of a single atom "v=spf1 -all".

Comment: Two things, I've updated my question, but I also followed your second comment, I added quotes around my spf record and it now passes!! Include that in your response and you win :) So basically, my TXT record now says "v=spf1 mx include:mail.example.com -all" with the quotes... and i also updated the mydomains to examples haha, didn't realize mydomain.com was a real company!

Comment: Great. Now your SPF is syntactically correct, and it is actually working, because the MX records cover the mail server(s) you are using to transfer mails. You may want to update it, so that it only contains those and only those servers which will send mails. For example:
"v=spf1 a:mail.example.com -all" or even "v=spf1 a -all" if example.com is the same server as mail.example.com.